# Connect between visual and oracle

Tags: oracle, ado.net

I need to make connection between visual studio 2013 and remote oracle database 10g when I open the connection show the following error message:

> An exception of type
>   'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception

I install Oracle data access and used `Imports Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`

```
Public Function Gett() As DataTable
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim st As String = "Data Source =    (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = tcp.world) (PROTOCOL = TCP)  (Host = 172.16.0.70) (Port = 1521)  ))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ORCL))) ; user id='cmn' ; password='cmn'"
    Dim sql As String = "select Top(1) * from FIN_VOUCHERS"
    Dim conn As New OracleConnection(st)
    conn.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(dt)
    conn.Close()

    Return dt

End Function
```

Note:
when I unplug network cable it show same messege , so i think the problem in my machine not in the server oracle version ..
how i know if oracle client in my machine is work well ??

Comment: please look to the attached image

Comment: Is there any way to use a try/catch block and inspect the exception?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. They are hard to read, can't be easily copy-pasted into an editor, and can't be found by the search function.

Comment: the Error messege is exist in the image

Comment: Which Oracle version does the server have? 10g R1 or 10g R2?

Comment: Don't paste screenshots! What is the full ConnectionString? (which is truncated by screenshot)

Comment: Dim st As String = "Data Source =    (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = tcp.world) (PROTOCOL = TCP)  (Host = 172.16.0.70) (Port = 1521)  ))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ORCL))) ; user id='cmn' ; password='cmn'"

Comment: Dears ..I pasted screenshot to more detailes..
Because I very need to Solution Now ..
So sorry

Comment: Don't put changes as comment, edit your question and add new information there. You will get quicker answer without screenshots. And please provide the error details (by clicking on "View Detail...")

Comment: It would be very nice to see Oracle exception text. Without it nobody can say what's wrong. Say, for example, you made typo in ip address - how we can handle this? BTW, try to connect with your connection string (without user/password) via SQL*Plus and publish result (with error text also).

Comment: Btw, does Oracle really can proceed SELECT TOP(1) query? :)

Comment: dear Sanders ..
the problem in Connection process .. the select statment is not important now –

Comment: @Awies, there are several open question which you did not answer yet: Which Oracle version is your database server - 10g R1 or 10g R2? What are the error **details**?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide any error detail I can just guess.

ODP.NET Managed Driver requires Oracle version 10g R2 or later. If your database server is 10g R1 then you cannot use it. In this case you must use an older version of ODP.NET **Unmanaged** Driver.

I am not sure about the quoting and additional space characters. Try this one instead:

```
Dim st As New OracleConnectionStringBuilder()
st.DataSource = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (COMMUNITY = tcp.world) (PROTOCOL = TCP)  (Host = 172.16.0.70) (Port = 1521)  ))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ORCL)))"
st.Password = "cmn"
st.UserID = "cmn"

Dim conn As New OracleConnection(st.ConnectionString)
```

Comment: thank you my  bro ..
but when i plug off the network cable .. i have same problem .. so i think this problem is in my machine and not check the remote server ..
can you help me .. 
which tool and version i need in my machine to make connection ??

Comment: You will not get any further help unless you provide us the error details!

Comment: Dear ..
sorry if my question is unclear
I need to make Connection with remote oracle database 10g
my machine use windows 8 , installed oracle client 10g and (oracle data tools for visual studio 2013) but the above message appeared to me !!
just I need to know , if I need to other tool to make connection ??
Or need to use other version of oracle client ?
Or any Suggestion

Comment: You don't need to install any Oracle Client when you use the ODP.NET Managed Driver. Apart from that: provide use the requested details.

Comment: this is very important information ..
OK ..  now .. I use  (oracle data tools for visual studio 2013) this include ODP.NET or I need other tools ??
-
In principle .. The connection to the database (con.open) shows this message
(An exception of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException' occurred in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: External component has thrown an exception)