# I need To make connection Between visual 2013 and remote oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, ado.net, oracle10g, odp.net

I need To make connection Between visual 2013 and remote oracle 10g database ..
I Downloaded ODP.NET 11 from

### [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacdev-4242174.html)

and install it ..
put when step 
con.open this messege shows >>

> ora-12514 tns listener does not currently know of service requested in
>   connect descriptor

what is the solution ??

my Connection string

```
(DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
        (ADDRESS = 
          (COMMUNITY = tcp.world)
          (PROTOCOL = TCP)
          (Host = 172.16.0.70)
          (Port = 1521)
        )
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = ORCL)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Do you think you get an answer for the same question but with the same lack of information? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48516588/connect-between-visual-and-oracle

Comment: What is the connection string? Do you use an `tnsnames.ora` file?

Comment: Are you able to connect with any other tool (e.g. sqlplus, SQL Developer) to the database using the same connection string?

Comment: Try `SERVICE_NAME = ORCL` instead of `SID = ORCL`

Comment: Dear ..
it is other problem ..
I downloaded odp.net 11 .. and get new messege ..
I can't use other tool to connect with oracle database .. and tried last change and it shows messege
(ora-1017 invalid username/password logon denied)
that is mean the connect Is success but the problem in user name ??

Comment: Then most likely the database is not up and running, i.e. the listener does not run.

Comment: how I can make it run ?

Comment: You should ask your DBA.